# Yank and paste - E353 nothing in register

Tags: vim

I've used Vim for many months now, and I haven't had any problems. But a few days ago something changed and I can't find the cause of this.

When I use `y$` to copy a line of a file, and go into another file to paste it here, I get the error `E353 nothing in register`. This has worked just fine until now.

What could be the cause for something like this?

Comment: Can you write (or read) to your `.viminfo` file? Non empty registers are stored in this file between vim sessions.

Comment: Try seeing if the error still works with `vim -u NONE`

Comment: What is the output of `:set clipboard`?

Comment: I can read my `.viminfo`, it is empty. On the other side, I can't write in...
When I do `vim -U NONE`, I see the version of vim. When I try again to copy/paste, it fails the same way...

Comment: `:set clipboard` => `E519: Non supported option: clipboard`

Comment: What is the output of `:set viminfo`?

Comment: `viminfo='100,<50,s10,h`

Comment: Just to be sure, are the source file and the destination file open in the same Vim instance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31478/discussion-between-flo-rahl-and-romainl)

Comment: So you don't have write access to `~/.viminfo`? What does `ls -l ~/.viminfo` in the terminal say?

Comment: Any resolution to this? Please post it back here, if so!

Comment: No resolution. I switched to another use of vim. Instead of using different instances of vim, I'm using the `:sp` command to split my screen in multiple windows, keeping only one instance, that permits to copy/paste through different files.

Comment: I am also having this issue. I closed other instances of mvim, restarted it, and still have the same problem. Used to work fine until a couple of days back.

Comment: What Vim version? What flavor? Is this reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Does adding the following to your .vimrc file help?

`set clipboard+=unnamed`